# how to replace a substring between tags in java

Tags: java

I want to replace a string if is not present between tags..
Example:
Replace `str1` by `str2` if its not present in `<>`.

input string

`<field1_str1>randomvalue_str1</field1_str1><field2_str1 > randomvalue_str1_random_value </field2_str1 >`

output string

`<field1_str1>randomvalue_str2</field1_str1 ><field2_str1 > randomvalue_str2_random_value </ field2_str1 >`

Comment: Is this homework or can you use an XML parser? Also, I've read the question a couple of times but I don't really understand what you'd want to do.

Comment: U can not use xml parser..because the tag name is unknown.

Comment: You can help me with pattern class if possible..thank you

Comment: I'm sure you tried something already.

Comment: I tried to use regular expressions. .but did not the desired result.

Comment: Str1 can appear both in <> and >< .So I need to replace the Str1 by Str2 when and only when its in ><.we need to keep the value as it is in <>.

Comment: @Yassin..I tried to use this pattern \\>(.*?)\\< to get the string between ><.but was not able to replace Str1 by Str2.

Comment: Before asking such question you should read all about regular expressions ) and try something with them at least ) Coz this what you asking is primitive )

Answer (score 0):

Although the example you gave doesnt really help, I'll give you the logic for the question you gave in the first line

```
Str str1="<Heylo>";
Str str2="Boo";
int stuff=hello.length();
if(str1.charAt(0).equals("<"); && str.charAt(stuff).equals(">")
System.out.println("It is in tags");
else
str1=str2;
```

Comment: Not serving my purpose..as the tag name and values are dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

Based off looking at your example of where you want replacement to occur, it seems like you want to replace the strings that occur between two XML tags. It seems easier to think about this as replacing the strings that occur between > and < instead of those that occur between < and >.

```
String input = "<field1_str1>randomvalue_str1</field1_str1><field2_str1 > randomvalue_str1_random_value </field2_str1 >";

String str1 = "str1";
String str2 = "str2";

String replace = input.replaceAll(">([^<]*?)" + str1, ">$1" + str2);
```

This replace looks for a > to start the match, since we don't want to match things inside of the tags. It will then match anything that isn't a < since that would end our match and start an XML tag, and it will continue to match until it finds str1. On a successful match it will add back the first part we matched on and replace str1 with str2. This code returns what you're looking for in your output string.